# How to write transition coverage between two enums?

Tags: system-verilog

```
enum {Idle, S1, S2} State;

covergroup cg_State @(posedge Clock);
  states      : coverpoint State;
  state_trans : coverpoint State {
    bins legal[] = ( Idle => S1, S2 ),
                   ( S1, S2 => Idle);
    bins idle[] = ( Idle [* 2:4] );
    bins illegal = default sequence; 
  }
endgroup
```

For a single enum I am aware that the transition coverage looks as above

In my case I have two enums which are represented as below,

```
typedef enum {RST=0,START=1,PAUSE=2,RESUME=3} instr_t;
typedef enum {IDLE=0,RUNNING=1,PAUSED=2,EXPIRED=3} state_t;
```

I am trying to write coverpoint for `IDLE => RST, START => RUNNING` etc but could not figure out a way to do this,

could anyone tell if there is any possible way to do this eg(`IDLE=> RST, IDLE => START` etc)

Answer (score 2):

Since both of them are two independent enums, it does not make sense to look for transition coverage across them. 
It makes more sense to do a cross coverage. 
When you mean (IDLE=> RST, IDLE => START ), you probably want a cross coverage that checks when state_t is in IDLE state,  instr_t is in RST or instr_t transitions from RST->START
And this can be done with cross coverage constructs